# Nav menu pushing to extreme right of page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is Angular 8 MVC C# application. I have been jumping between two issues. If I fix one the other one springs up.

In the css I am defining

```
*,
html,
body
{
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

When I have above, the menu shifts to right of page and is outside of visible area of web page. Image 1 [image: image shifts to right]

```
*,
html,
body
{
padding-right: 1px;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

To fix above issue, I tried adding padding-right so that nav links do not shift to right. but by doing so, a gap between top menus and these nav menus appear. Image 2[image: Gap appears from top menu to nav links]
I cannot figure out how to reduce this gap

Please guide if there's another way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the HTML it will be easier to make suggestions but have you tried putting the 2 elements, 'top menus' and 'nav menus'. By putting them in div tags it will allow you to have different styling to both of them.

```
<style>
    .top-menu {
        /*STYLING FOR THE TOP MENU GOES HERE*/
    }
    .nav-menu {
        /*STYLING FOR THE NAV MENU GOES HERE*/
    }
</style>

<div class="nav-menu">
    <!-- put the HTML for the nav menu here -->
</div>
<div class="top-menu">
    <!-- put the HTML for the top menu here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Top menu is coming from a department wide Nuget package. I have no control over that.

Comment: the issue started occurring when I added font-size for the website